# How to read data from event table in execution plan in wso2 DAS 3.0.1

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

I am using DAS 3.0.1 in my project where I need to read data from event table in execution plan.

Actually I am trying to update only one column in the event table but it creates new entry with only that column instead of updating in the event table.

Is there any way to update only particular column by applying filter criteria in the execution plan.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If the table contains several attributes such as att1, att2, att3. Then you can define the table (if the name is "YourEventTableName") as follows.

```
define table YourEventTableName (tableAtt1 int, tableAtt2 string, tableAtt3 string);
```

The theres a stream (if the name is "YourEventStream") you can define the stream as

```
define stream YourEventStream (streamAtt int, streamAtt2 string);
```

Assume that, you need to update tableAtt1 attribute from the streamAtt attribute value in YourEventStream, in the table row which contains "aaa" as tableAtt3.

```
from YourEventStream 
select streamAtt as tableAtt1
update YourEventTableName
    on YourEventTableName.tableAtt3 == "aaa";
```

Assume that, you need to update tableAtt1 attribute from the streamAtt attribute value in YourEventStream, in the table row which contains "aaa" as tableAtt3.

```
from YourEventStream 
select streamAtt as tableAtt1
update YourEventTableName
    on YourEventTableName.tableAtt3 == streamAtt2;
```

Refer to the [Siddhi documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP410/SiddhiQL+Guide+3.0#SiddhiQLGuide3.0-Update) for more information.

When validating your query i found some issues. the following is the updating query you have.

```
from InStream 
select StatusDescription as StatusDescription 
update NGPOCYTEST 
    ON NGPOCYTEST.StatusDescription == StatusDescription
```

the "select" section of the query should have the attribute values that needs to update the table. And it should be a attribute in the "InStream". I cannot find an attribute called "StatusDescription" in your "InStream". Anyway what you need to do is,

```
from InStream 
select $streamAttributeName$ as $tableColumnName$ 
update NGPOCYTEST 
    ON NGPOCYTEST.StatusDescription == $anotherStreamAttributeNameOrTheSame$
```

$streamAttributeName$ - the name of the stream attribute which contains the value you need to update the particular column from.

$tableColumnName$ - is the column you need to update in your table which can be either PNumber, CNumber, SCode string, etc.

$anotherStreamAttributeNameOrTheSame$ - the name of the stream attribute which contains the value that should be satisfied between the table column and the stream in order to update the table. This can be an attribute name of the stream

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Comment: This is not working for me. Please see my response as below.

Comment: Ramindu, I tried with the above syntax but it is not working for me. I have posted the Execution plan as below. Could you please review it and let me know if anything is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response. I tried with it but it didnt work for me.

I have one event table NGPOCYTEST where I store below parameters. (PNumber int, CNumber string, SCode string, StatusDescription string, PCode string, UpDate string, PoDate string, CompanyID int, Product string);

I have one stream NgStream as below.
(CNumber string, CompanyAbbr string, NgID string, NgDate string, NgCategory string, NgReason string, DocumentNumber string, EventType string, ResolveCode string, ResolveDate string)

Let me tell you in detail business requirement.

I have NgStream (with different parameters from NGPOCYTEST tables) received on the DAS as http request. I am storing this stream in seperate table in DAS(SQL server). 
If I received this request I need to update the status(Only one column) in the NGPOCYTEST in REAL TIME. 
So I have written an execution plan to update status in real time as below. Unfortunately status in the NGPOCYTEST is not getting updated. Please let me know if I did anything wrong.

---

@from(eventtable='analytics.table', jdbc.url='jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=###', username='***', password='****', driver.name='com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver', table.name='NGPOCYTEST')

define table NGPOCYTEST (PNumber int, CNumber string, SCode string, StatusDescription string, PCode string, UpDate string, PoDate string, CompanyID int, Prdct string);

@Import('NgStream:1.0.0')
define stream InStream (CNumber string, CompanyAbbr string, NgID string, NgDate string, NgCategory string, NgReason string, DocuNo string, EvType string, ResCode string, ResDate string)

from InStream
select StatusDescription as StatusDescription
update NGPOCYTEST
    ON NGPOCYTEST.StatusDescription == StatusDescription

---